# Decorate BaseController with Scrutor in .netCore 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, decorator, scrutor

I have an application in .net core 3.1 with angular front end. I want to use the decorator to the base controller in order to log CUD operations in the entire application. I am using Scrutor nuget package in the project.

The Base Controller is the following

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Xenagos.Data;
using Xenagos.Data.EFCore;
using Xenagos.ViewModels;

namespace Xenagos.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public abstract class BaseController<TEntity, TViewEntity, TRepository> : ControllerBase, IBaseController<TEntity, TViewEntity> 
        where TEntity : class
        where TViewEntity : class, IViewEntity
        where TRepository : IRepository<TEntity>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<TEntity> repository;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public BaseController(TRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }


        // GET: api/[controller]
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<ComplexData<TViewEntity>>> Get()
        {
            var results = await repository.GetAll();
            List<TViewEntity> resultsView =
                this.mapper.Map<List<TEntity>, List<TViewEntity>>(results);
            return Ok(new ComplexData<TViewEntity>(resultsView));
        }

        // GET: api/[controller]/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> Get(int id)
        {
            var entity = await repository.Get(id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return entity;
        }

        // PUT: api/[controller]/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, TViewEntity entity)
        {
            if (!id.Equals(entity.Id))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            await repository.Update(this.mapper.Map<TEntity>(entity));
            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/[controller]
        [HttpPost]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> Post(TViewEntity entity)
        {
            await repository.Add(this.mapper.Map<TEntity>(entity));
            return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = entity.Id }, entity);
        }

        // DELETE: api/[controller]/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TViewEntity>> Delete(int id)
        {
            var entity = await repository.Delete(id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return this.mapper.Map<TViewEntity>(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

The decorator I made is the following

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xenagos.Controllers;
using Xenagos.ViewModels;

namespace Xenagos.Data
{
    public class LoggingDecorator<T, TViewEntity, TRepository> : IBaseController<T, TViewEntity>
        where T : class
        where TViewEntity : class, IViewEntity
        where TRepository : IRepository<T>
    {

        private IBaseController<T, TViewEntity> _baseController;
        private readonly ILogger<LoggingDecorator<T, TViewEntity, TRepository>> _logger;

        public LoggingDecorator(IBaseController<T, TViewEntity> baseController, ILogger<LoggingDecorator<T, TViewEntity, TRepository>> logger)
        {
            _baseController = baseController;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        Task<ActionResult<TViewEntity>> IBaseController<T, TViewEntity>.Delete(int id)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"Deleting record from ... with ID:{id}");
            Task<ActionResult<TViewEntity>> result = _baseController.Delete(id);

            return result;
        }

        public Task<ActionResult<ComplexData<TViewEntity>>> Get()
        {
            return _baseController.Get();
        }

        Task<ActionResult<T>> IBaseController<T, TViewEntity>.Get(int id)
        {
            return _baseController.Get(id);
        }

        public Task<ActionResult<T>> Post(TViewEntity entity)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"Adding new record from ... with object data :{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity)}");
            return _baseController.Post(entity);
        }

        public Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, TViewEntity entity)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"updating record from ... with object data :{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity)}");
            Task<IActionResult> result = _baseController.Put(id, entity);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

In the startup class in the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)` I use the following lines

```
services.AddScoped<IBaseController<Models.Property, PropertyViewModel>, BaseController<Models.Property, PropertyViewModel, PropertyRepository>>();
            services.Decorate<IBaseController<Models.Property, PropertyViewModel>, LoggingDecorator<Models.Property, PropertyViewModel, PropertyRepository>>();
```

I have extracted an Interface from the base controller, on top of all the previous actions.
While the application runs, it does not call/pass-through the decorator. What I'm missing here ?
I haven't used the decorator pattern with .net core and dependency injection before. All the added code is in the backend only, I haven't altered the front end at all.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include the registration of your non-abstract Controller?

Comment: The question is if it is even possible to do this with the controller. It is the `BaseController` that you have decorated with `[ApiController]` which asp.net uses to detect the controllers in your project. So it will always be the classes with that attribute being resolved and not your `LoggingDecorator` when a request is comming in. You don't need to register the controller for them to work. I would think you can use structor for anything else but the controllers. A safer bet for this might be to use Action filters instead.

Comment: @devNull I've extracted an interface from the non-abstract controller as well, and added it as scoped. It didn't help so far. Should I do anything else as well ?

Comment: @Michael, so, If I understood, I should try to decorate the class that it is invoked form the controller that performs the action (e.g. Update)?

Comment: @Tony, If you want to stick to `structor` then yes. But I think there are other solutions out there.

Comment: You can't decorate controllers in ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core uses the controller's metadata on the controller's type which can't be accessed when the controller is decorated. The way to attach cross-cutting concerns to controllers in ASP.NET Core is through middleware and action filters.

Comment: @Steven, I'm taking the action filter approach, the only thing I need to do in order to test it, is to check how I can pass the ILoggerFactory as a parameter in the startup.cs when I'm adding MVC filters.

Comment: @Tony you don't need action filters to log data operations. EF/EF Core already provide data operation logging. Action filters can provide *action* logging. Using a "generic" repository is a bad idea too, as DbSet is already a repository, a DbContext already implements Unit-of-Work

Comment: @Tony you should check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)  to understand the serious problems caused by a "generic" repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging enter/exit on controller actions using `ActionFilter`:

```
public class LoggingActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    ILogger _logger;
    public LoggingActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LoggingActionFilter>();
    }
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
        _logger.LogInformation($"Action '{context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}' executing");
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
        _logger.LogInformation($"Action '{context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}' executed");
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add<LoggingActionFilter>();
    });
```

You might also want to implement `IAsyncActionFilter` for the async actions.

To read more about action filters, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters).

You can also add exception filters to log all exceptions.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'll try to implement it and let you know of the results

Comment: that was really helpful! thank you for your help. One question though, on the snippet you posted, you add a new LoggingActionFilter object to the MVC filters. On the first snippet you have placed a constructor parameter. How can I pass the ILoggerFacotry to the object instantiation on the MVC filters when I add it ?

Comment: Ahh yes, my mistake. You should use the generic version and asp.net will use the serviceProvider. Edited my answer.